# Converting / interpolating delimited text csv points grid to surface

Tags: qgis, convert, interpolation, text

I have 12 delimited text csv files with regular pseudo-gridded points for temperature and salinity which look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQtvM.jpg) when zoomed in (inc distances) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LENI.jpg) when zoomed out. I'm trying to convert them to a smooth surface layer - assumedly interpolated - but using the interpolation plugin on a vector layer saved from one of the csv's produced [this](https://imgur.com/7knIFfN) kind of output, irrespective of how many columns I use.

How do I turn my grids of dots into a nice smooth surface that I can use colour interpolation on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a regular point grid, you can use Raster | Conversion | Rasterize to create a raster with exactly the attribute values of the input points converted onto raster values. No interpolation or other manipulation of attribute/raster values is applied.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the interpolation functions in ArcGIS. Since they are regularly spaced, [Inverse Distance Weighted](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/how-idw-works.htm) would work without making too many assumptions.