# Graduated colouring Voronoi polygons? (QGis)

Tags: qgis, layers, voronoi-thiessen, color, debugging

I've got a huge database of depth points for the whole Irish sea which I'd like to be a nice smooth surface, or at least have a depth value associated with the entire area (i.e. include the inter-point spaces). I've tried interpolation but [can't get it to work well](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65385/convert-interpolate-delimited-text-csv-points-grid-to-surface), so I thought to make Voronoi polygons from the points, and then graduated colour them.

Problem: In 2.1 master, a blank column is created in the Voronoi polygons shapefile, and switching from single symbol: [image: single symbol] towards graduated results in a complete blank: [image: complete blank]. This even happens with the csv file, from dots: [image: dots] towards blank: [image: blank]. Andre Joost got around [a similar problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72284/why-are-some-values-missing-from-the-imported-csv) by using semicolon delimited files, but it feels to me like this is a genuine bug in master, especially given the same files don't blank the Voronoi shapefile in DuFour: [image: don't blank the Voronoi shapefile in DuFour]. Has anyone else experienced this? I'm about to raise it on QGis hub.

Question: can I colour the Voronoi polygons using the depth value? The Voronoi shapefile has depth as a field but it doesn't do anything - possibly it doesn't know how to deal with the fact that each Voronoi polygon has a number of depths equal to its number of edges (usually 4 in my case here). Can I colour them using the depth value from the points file somehow?

Comment: you seem to have a regular grid, so why not convert it to raster ? Have you checked that the field you want to symbolize is of numeric type ?

Comment: seems that it is a regular grid all over (for some reason zooming out adds weird overlaps which make it look otherwise). Raster here we come, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give the value of your points to your polygons using the spatial join (vector > management tools). Then you will have a depth value for all your polygons.

Comment: I'll try this, then the raster idea above. The benefit of this method is that it fills odd-shaped the coastal voronois with values, which the raster will only partially do. Thanks!